# Google Search Bar Widget is gone from Galaxy S5, it is not in the widgets section anymore

Tags: app-widgets, google, samsung-galaxy-s-5, search

My Google Search Bar went missing (I did not delete it). Every fix says to hold down the home screen and re-add it, however, it is NOT in the widgets section anymore. It is completely missing.

I've tried finding it in Play Store (not there), I've tried using a different launcher other than Touchwiz (Nova), etc. I just want the bar back and have it Google Voice enabled.

Answer (score 1):

The same thing happened to me and here's what worked:

Go to Application Manager and keep rolling right until you get to the "Turned Off" header. My Google Search was there. I simply had to turn it back on and then it appeared back in the widget options and I was able to pick it up from there and move it to the home screen.

Comment: What is the "Application Manager"?

Answer (score 0):

Lost my Google toolbar after a Lollipop update.  Find a space on your main screen (without icons) and hard press for a second or two until your widgets screen appears.  Flip through the screens until you locate the Google toolbar.  Press down on it and move it to your main screen.  Voila!!  Problem solved.  Hope this helps.

Comment: OP said : *Every fix says to hold down the home screen and re-add it, however, it is NOT in the widgets section anymore. It is completely missing.*. Do you realize it now? Its not there in the Widgets anymore.