# Google Search Bar Missing (after OTA update)

Tags: 4.4-kitkat, google-search

I recently discovered the Google search bar which used to appear between the notification area and the topmost Widget has disappeared. Shortly before, I had received a largish OTA system update and at around the same time my father had gotten at my phone and accidentally knocked some things off the screen the way that fathers will.

Note that this is not the search *widget*, but the toolbar that appears (appeared) *above* the widgets.

I found one similar question
["Google Search Bar Widget is gone from Galaxy S5, it is not in the widgets section anymore"](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/106720/google-search-bar-widget-is-gone-from-galaxy-s5-it-is-not-in-the-widgets-sectio)
but that didn't solve my problem. (The toolbar does *not* appear on the "Disabled" tab of App Manager.)

I have a Kyocera DuraForce E6560C running Android 4.4.2 unrooted. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried _clearing data_ of your stock launcher?  _Settings_ -> _Apps_ -> _All_ (Tab) -> _StockLauncherName_ -> _Clear data_ -> _OK_

Comment: The closest match I can find for *StockLauncherName* is **Launcher**. When I tap "Clear Data" the warning is sufficiently dire-sounding that No, I have not done that.

Comment: Do you have any apps called _Kyocera Home_ or such?I have _Touchwiz home_ on my samsung and _Xperia Home_ on Sony device. I don't know about this device. Also there's a [XDA-super thread on Kyocera Duraforce](http://forum.xda-developers.com/general/general/kyocera-duraforce-super-thread-t3133882) with information about your device. If possible install [APK extractor](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.ext.ui) and Open App-> _App settings_ ->Toggle __OFF__ `Show All Applications` -> Back to App main screen -> _Menu_ (option overflow button) -> _Show system Apps_ (NO root needed).

Comment: Thanks for the link. It'll take me some time to read through it. I'm new to Android, though, so could you please explain what APK Extractor will do for me?

Comment: It's built to extract apps to your sdcard for installation later but you can use it see the _system apps_ by filtering. You may get the launcher name there. And clearing data only deletes your settings and widgets. No data other than that is lost

Comment: @DarwinvonCorax- Nothing serious happens if you clear data and cache of Launcher. Any previous configs related to homescreen will be lost. That is it.

Comment: Didn't work, and now I have to track down and organize all my apps and widgits again.

Comment: How about installing a new Home/Launcher app? This is Google Now Launcher and has decent reviews: 
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.launcher

Answer (score 1):

The widget may be listed under the ridiculously renamed Google Search app called "Launcher3" - find the 4x1 widget and drag to the desktop.

Comment: That isn't it. Whatever this thing was, I'm fairly certain it wasn't a widget.