# Restore Google Search to home screen

Tags: google, search

How do I restore the Google search bar to the home screen of a Motto z?

Comment: Widget? Try long-hold on empty space of the homescreen and see what you get.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Google Search Bar Missing (after OTA update)](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/129728/google-search-bar-missing-after-ota-update)

Answer (score 1):

open your lock screen .

- long click on your home screen
- click on widget section
- select google search
- drag it to your desire location on screen.